# "chrome did not shut down properly" every time it starts up

Tags: google-chrome

For a few months, Chrome on my Windows XP SP3 computer had the following symptoms:

- Takes a few minutes to shut down. (Maxes out a core while doing so.)
- Takes a few minutes to start up.
- When it starts up, only one empty window appears, with the message "chrome did not shut down properly" at the top in yellow.
- Clicking the message doesn't do anything immediately, but after another minute or two the tabs are restored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [a partial solution here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/VNi-Ub-lraY), the problem was fixed by deleting the `*.tmp` files in the following two directories:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

Or for Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\
```

There were 65,535 `*.tmp` files in each! They had names like `1.tmp` through to `FFFF.tmp`. All of these files were empty. It took quite a bit of time to even list the files in each directory, and Windows Explorer stalled while trying to operate on them, so I used bash to delete them. It seems that the reason for the slow-downs and the incorrect shutdowns of Chrome was that it was trying to access the files in some way. Maybe it was only trying to list the files in the directory, which by itself would take a long time.

Now Chrome starts up instantly, and shuts down almost instantly, and does not display the message.